# Unable to find an installation of R on the system (which R didn't return valid output); Unable to locate R binary by scanning standard locations

Tags: terminal, rstudio, ubuntu-16.04

Step 1: Download R-studio from

```
https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/
```

Step 2: Open terminal and use this command

```
sudo dpkg -i rstudio-1.0.136-amd64.deb
```

Step 3: Launch R Studio from terminal:

```
rstudio
```

This throws an error:

```
Unable to find an installation of R on the system (which R didn't return valid output); Unable to locate R binary by scanning standard locations
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/209074748-Installing-RStudio-Desktop-on-Ubuntu-16-04-LTS

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It tells you exactly what the problem is. You didn't install R. RStudio is a very nice IDE for R but you don't automatically get R installed just by installing RStudio. Follow the instructions here  https://cran.r-project.org or use your package manager to install R.